# SQL Server 2008 R2 Installation Error "Trust Relationship Failed"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, installation, sql-server-2008-r2

When I install SQL Server 2008 R2, the Database Engine Services feature don't install due to the error "The Trust Relationship between the primary domain and the trusted domain failed."

For context, I'm trying to get into ASP.NET MVC3 and when I try to add/browse a database in Visual Studio 2010, I get errors saying that it can't connect to the SQL Express database, Error 40. When I run the SQL Server Configuration Manager, and select the SQL Server Services, I get "The remote procedure call failed [0x800706be]"

I did some research, regarding this error 40; I've tried, to run Server Configuration Manager as a Administrator, change the TCP/IP settings in Client Protocols to Enabled, and it still didn't work. I uninstalled SQL Server 2008 R2 and reinstalled it and found that the Database Engine Services and SQL Server Replication failed to install, with the error message "The Trust Relationship between the primary domain and the trusted domain failed."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete EVERYTHING.

This is dedicated to anyone who thought like me and thought you could get rid of one or two things, and reinstall. Anything with SQL Server, delete it. Make that Add/Remove Programs as clean as possible before reinstalling the server.

Also, be sure to have administrative rights/run as Admin turned on. Otherwise you may have a SQLEXPRESS server running, but you can't access it (or because of my work computer) delete it due to a user rights issue that goes beyond the scope of Stack Overflow. :)

In that case, you should be able to install a new instance (I.E. SQLEXPRESS1). Just be sure to check your data connection strings. :)